# Detect which element called a function, within function without passing it as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

This is my html markup:

```
<a onclick="cart.add('10');" class="product-10">Add to cart</a>
<a onclick="cart.add('11');" class="product-11">Add to cart</a>
<a onclick="cart.add('12');" class="product-12">Add to cart</a>
```

And this is my javascript object:

```
var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id) {
        //What I want console.log(element_that_was_clicked.attr('class'));
    }
}
```

Is there a way to detect which `a` called `cart.add` without editing html markup?

**UPDATE**

the `a` tag has no `class`, I added those classes just for demo, actually I need `a` object itself, because I want to access to its next sibling, my markup is something like this:

```
<div><a onclick="cart.add('10');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
```

And I want:

```
var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id) {
        //What I want console.log(element_that_was_clicked.next().val());
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `onclick="cart.add(this, '10');"` and `'add': function(element, product_id) {`

Comment: Yes, I know that, but I'm looking for a way to do this without editing html part.

Comment: then you do away with `onclick="cart.add('10');"` and use unobtrusive event handler

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all remove inline `onclick` (it is bad practice) and register an event listener:

**HTML**

```
<a id="10" class="product-10">Add to cart</a>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
   var product_id = $(this).attr('id'); // Or any other attribute
   cart.add(product_id);
});
```

**EDIT**

Check this workaround, basically, by executing `removeInlineHandlers` you remove the inline `onclick` property and assign an event handler that calls the `add` function passing the clicked element:

```js
function removeInlineHandlers() {
  $('a').each(function() {
    var that = $(this);
    var thisId = that.attr('onclick').match(/\d+/);    
    that.removeAttr('onclick')        
        .on('click', function() {
           cart.add(thisId, that);
        });
  })
}

var cart = {
    'add': function(product_id, elem) {
        alert('Added id: ' + product_id + ' with quantity of: ' + elem.next('input').val());
    }
}

removeInlineHandlers();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a onclick="cart.add('10');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" />
<a onclick="cart.add('11');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" />
<a onclick="cart.add('12');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" />
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please see my updated question. also I'm looking for a way to do this without editing html part.

Answer (score 1):

The best or ideal way is to use `jQuery` event listener. Personally, I will find a way to change the HTML instead.

But if you **really really can't** change the HTML, you can do use the `onclick` attribute as a selector. This is bad practise.

Something Like:

```js
var cart = {
  'add': function(product_id) {
    //$("[onclick=\"cart.add('" + product_id + "');\"]") <-- Getting the clicked a using onclick attribute
    $("[onclick=\"cart.add('" + product_id + "');\"]").next().val("TEST");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a onclick="cart.add('10');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
<div><a onclick="cart.add('11');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
<div><a onclick="cart.add('12');">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
```

---

The ideal is adding an event listener using a class. Like:

```js
$(function(){
    $(".product").click(function(){
        $(this).next().val("TEST");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><a class="product">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
<div><a class="product">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
<div><a class="product">Add to cart</a><input type="text" name="quantity" /></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please see my updated question.